# Comparing equality between sum and constant

Tags: python, debugging, numpy

I have the following code snippet ...

```
try:
    assert(float(elem[0]+elem[1])==1.0)
except AssertionError:
    print float(elem[0]+elem[1]), elem[0]+elem[1]
```

... where elem is a two element numpy array (and elem[0] and elem[1] are of type numpy.float64).  For my array, the above code always prints...

```
1.0, 1.0
```

... to stdout and I cannot figure out why.  If someone could offer some guidance, I would appreciate it.  Please let me know if more information is required to help.

EDIT:

The value of elem[0] is 0.168270720826 and the value of elem[1] is 0.831729279174.

Comment: exactly what are the values of elem[0] & elem[1] separately?

Comment: Do a `print repr(float(elem[0]+elem[1]))` and see if that makes it clear.

Comment: The values you show in your edit are *wrong*. If you simply print a floating point value you'll get something that's rounded. You need to print the `repr` of the number as I said before.

Comment: Nope.  I'm not  sure why you think this is the case, but it's not the behavior I observed.

Comment: Are you saying that `print str(elem[0]),repr(elem[0])` prints two numbers that are identical?

Comment: No, I didn't print repr(elem[0]), I only printed float(elem[0]) (which yielded the values in my edit).  I did print repr(elem[0]+elem[1]) which returned helpful, new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare floating point numbers, always test a range of acceptable values rather than comparing directly for equality. So for your assert try this instead:

```
assert( abs(float(elem[0]+elem[1])-1.0) < 0.00005)
```

Where 0.00005 is the range of values that are considered equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Some floating point implementations create roundoff far out in the least significant bits that are not always displayed when printed.  So it is possible that what you really are getting from float(e0+e1) is something like 1.00000000001 and print is rounding it down.
(Can't tell for sure from the sample.)